# When should I use _id in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb

MongoDB has a field for every document called `_id`. I see people using it everywhere as a primary key, and using it in queries to find documents by the `_id`.

This field defaults to using an ObjectId which is auto-generated, an example is:

```
db.tasks.findOne() {
    _id: ObjectID("ADF9"), 
    description: "Write lesson plan",
    due_date:  ISODate("2014-04-01"),
    owner: ObjectID("AAF1")     // Reference to another document
}
```

But in JavaScript, the underscore behind a field in an object is a convention for private, and as MongoDB uses JSON (specifically, BSON), should I be using these `_id`s for querying, finding and describing relationships between documents? it doesn't seem right.

I saw that MongoDB has a way to generate UUID https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/UUID

Should I forget that _id property, and create my own indexed id property with an UUID?

Answer (score 1):

Use UUIDs for user-generated content, e.g. to name image uploads. UUIDs can be exposed to the user in an URL or when the user inspects an image on the client-side. For everything that is on the server/not exposed to the user, there is no need to generate a UUID, and using the auto-generated `_id` is preferred.

An simple example of using UUID would be:

```
const uuid = require('uuid');

exports.nameFile= async (req, res, next) => {
  req.body.photo = `${uuid.v4()}.${extension}`;
  next();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

How MongoDB names its things should not interfere in how you name your things. If data sent by third-party hurts the conventions you agreed to follow, you have to transform that data into the format you want as soon as it arrives in your application.

An example based in your case:

```
function findTaskById(id) {
    var result = db.tasks.findOne({"_id": id});

    var task = {
        id: result._id,
        description: result.description,
        something: result.something  
    };
    return task;
}
```

This way you isolate the use of Mongo's `_id` into the layer of your application that is responsible to interact with the database. In all other places you need task, you can use `task.id`.